Nuance of 今回の件もあるし、出来る限りの無茶は聞かせてもらうつもり
I met this difficult sentence while reading a novel, and all i can guess about its nuance is :"Including this event/incident(of the invitation to join my army ad participate in the coalition army), i will try my best to listen to anything you want to say to me, no matter how unreasonable/absurd it is." Much thanks if someone could correct my nuance understanding if I was wrong.
Novel context: Main character /一刀 is working for a clan leader name 桃香 (together with 1 of her military advisor 朱里).One day a close friend of the clan leader 公孫賛/白蓮ちゃん came by her city ,who's also a province governor for the Imperial court, together with her province's army + other province's army and their own generals 雷々+電々 +孫乾 and their teacher 風鈴 (who's received exiled sentence in the province of the province governor 公孫賛, she's supposedly not allowed to travel outside that province according to the Imperial court's rule). The province governor 公孫賛 asked the clan leader and protagonist if they want to participate into her hidden plan, which is to join the Anti 董卓 coalition army ,but actually not to kill 董卓 and instead try to save her from being executed.
(*Note: the clan leader 桃香 + the province governor 公孫賛 were both old students of 風鈴-sensei, before they became officials. The character 董卓 had previously made a coup/revolt inside the Imperial court, executed many corrupted officials + replace a new emperor with the reason of trying to save the country. So 董卓 had became an public enemy of other vassals in the country, and they created an "Anti 董卓 coalition army" to defeat her and restore the old emperor.)
桃香「それで、白蓮ちゃんのお話って？」
公孫賛「それなんだけどな。話があるのは私じゃなくて……」
風鈴「…………桃香ちゃん」
桃香「先生！？」
孫乾たちに連れて来られたのは、追放刑を受けて薊から出られないはずの、風鈴さんだった。
一刀「……公孫賛、これって！」
風鈴「……ごめんなさい。でも、どうしても月ちゃんの気持ちが知りたくて……白蓮ちゃんに無理を言って、ここまで同行させてもらったの」
公孫賛「大問題なのは私にだってわかってるよ。でも……先生に平伏までされたら、嫌だなんて言えないだろ。董卓の件は、私もずっと疑問に思ってたしな」
桃香「じゃあ、白蓮ちゃん。もしかして……」
公孫賛「ああ。私たちは、連合には参加するけど……董卓を討伐するんじゃなくて、助けるために動く。少なくとも、断ずるのはその本心を確かめてからだ」
朱里「それは……徐州の方もご承知なのですか？」
身内も同然の雷々たちはともかくとして、孫乾が風鈴さんを連れてきたって事は、承知の上ではあるんだろうけど。
雷々「雷々たちも、董卓さんは助けたいもん」
電々「そうそう。徐州の賊の平定も、董卓さんがたくさん応援を出してくれたんだよ」
孫乾「はい。仲穎殿は徐州にとっても大恩がありますので。この件も踏まえた上で、全ての判断は公孫賛さまにお預けしております」
公孫賛「けど……事が事だからな。反董卓の連合みんなを出し抜こうっていうんだ。一歩間違えたら、連合全員を敵に回す羽目になる」
公孫賛「徐州の連中は、聞いてなかったで通す建前にはなってるけど、桃香はそれも難しいだろうからな」
それはそうだ。三人の関係を少しでも調べれば、公孫賛と風鈴さんの企みに桃香が無関係だなんて思わないだろう。
朱里「……だから、返答は軍を平原に入れてからで良いと」
公孫賛「どこに間者がいるかもわかんないし、事前に妙な動きを察知されるわけにもいかなくてな」
公孫賛「出立は明日の朝になるから、それまでに答えてくれれば良い」
公孫賛「考える時間が短くて申し訳ないけど……反対なら、せめて私たちを見逃して、この部屋での事を忘れてくれたら助かる」
桃香「…………」
公孫賛「で、桃香の話って何だ？今回の件もあるし、出来る限りの無茶は聞かせてもらうつもりだけど……」

「今回の件もあるし」 doesn't mean what you think it means, namely "including what is going on this time". It means something along the lines of "considering what's going on this time" or more precisely "since I/we owe you for what is going on this time or for what you are doing for me/us this time", basically suggesting the speaker acknowledges a favor owed to the listener. And that's why the speaker goes on to say: "I intend to listen to any difficult/absurd/nonsensical things/requests you may have to say."

@desmo Please post this as an answer rather than a comment. If a question is answered with a comment, the system will consider it unresolved and keep bumping it.

@naruto I didn't write an answer to this question because I felt like I'd have to explain the use of も and し here and cite past answers from the archive. I didn't think I was able to explain them clearly enough. Also locating the best answers in the archive seemed daunting too.

Appreciates @desmo and naruto for your fast help ! Please have this

You seem to have temporarily forgotten that し is a (non-exhaustive) reason marker. 今回の件もあるし means not "including this issue" but "since there's this issue (which I asked you to keep a secret)" or "since we already have this situation on our hands".
公孫賛 is saying that, since she already asked 桃香 to "forget about this at least", it would serve as one of the reasons why she's willing to help 桃香 as much as possible in return.
